# Restricting senders that can be used by an API Key in Sendgrid

Tags: email, sendgrid

I completed Domain Authentication on my Sendgrid account and after that I can successfully send emails using the SMTP API from any email in my domain.

What I would like to achieve is restrict the "allowed" senders per key - e.g. create a `foo` api key that only allows sending from `foo@mydomain.com`. I can't seem to find it in any settings, is that possible?

Alternatively I'd like to tat least create an allowlist of emails that can be used as senders. I'm only using the SMTP API.